# Read only few columns from excel sheet

Tags: java, excel

I'm writing a Java program to fetch data from Excel sheet.

From the below program, i'm able to retrieve the entire data.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Column;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadData {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "resource", "null" })
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // get file
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(
                new File("C:\\A2015.xlsx"));

        // create book holding object
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fin);

        // get sheet

        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        // iterate through rows

        Iterator<Row> rowIt = sheet.rowIterator();

        while (rowIt.hasNext()) {
            XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rowIt.next();

            // iterate through Columns

            Iterator<Cell> colIt = row.cellIterator();
            while (colIt.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = colIt.next();
                System.out.println(cell.toString());
            }
            System.out.println();

        }

    }
}
```

But here my case is there are nearly 45-47 columns and out of there there is some data which is not required(for me, but needed for some other teams). Every column has a heading, and out of these 45-47 columns i want to pull data only from 12 columns, and there are randomly placed between the rest of columns in Excel sheet.

My question is, is there a way to iterate through all the rows and get data from these 12 columns only by using the Heading, If so can you please let me know how to extract it.

I'm using Apache POI.

Thanks

Comment: do you mean you want to fetch only columns which matches column header which is defined at row 1?

Comment: What about using  *row.getCell(int cellnum)* method?

Comment: Here i have 45-47 columns, is there another type, based on the column heading defined in the top, or do we need to do it only using column number?, since my columns are like AA,AB,AG,AH,AK,AT,AU. and i need to retrieve text from these columns

Comment: Why don't you iterate over the column names once, store the indexes of the columns you require, and then iterate over the rows getting the values from cells at those indexes?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static short getCellNum(String cellCode)throws InvalidNameException{
       char[] cellCodeU = cellCode.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
       int length = cellCodeU.length;
       int cellNumber = 0;
       for (int j=0;j<length;j++){
          if (cellCodeU[j]<'A' || cellCodeU[j]>'Z')
            throw new InvalidNameException("Wrong column index: " + cellCode);
          cellNumber = cellNumber*CELL_NUMBER_IN_SHEET + (cellCodeU[j]-64);
       }
       cellNumber-=1;
       if (cellNumber<0) 
          throw new InvalidNameException("Wrong column index: " + cellCode);
       return (short)cellNumber;
    }


 String columnsToRead = new String[]{"AA", "AB", "AU"};

 while (rowIt.hasNext()) {
        XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rowIt.next();
        for (int a = 0; a < columnsToRead.length; a++){
            Cell cell = getCell(getCellNum(columnsToRead[a]));
            System.out.println(cell.toString());   
        }
 }
```